# Messenger not recognize GET parameters

Tags: facebook, get, facebook-messenger-bot, external-links

I'm using the messenger API to send messages to facebook, in that messages sometimes i have links to an external website with get parameters.

Like: http://example.com?example=true

The main problem is that messenger only recognizes http://example.com as an link and i truly need the GET parameter.

There is anyway to fix this?

Ty,
Rui

Comment: Sounds like you neglected to apply proper URL-encoding ...

Comment: CBroe, can you give me more information about that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding // Can you show your API call?

Comment: Ty CBroe, i found the solution, that was not the encoding format, my problem was that i forget to put the / before the ? mark.

Before:
http://example.com?example=true
Now:
http://example.com/?example=true

Comment: Ah, so that’s rather an issue with your site then. (A redirect to add a missing trailing slash in the URL path is common practice, but it should not discard the query string while doing so.)

Comment: Yeh, You are right, Ty anyway ;)